# Is this gap under my patio sidelights okay?

Tags: patio, threshold

As part of a larger remodel, my contractor installed new sidelights by our kitchen patio doors. But the outdoor side of the threshold on which the sidelights sit seems to be cracked and not filled. Is this okay? Apart from the obvious aesthetic issue, I mean, is there a structural issue with having a gap in the concrete like this? Should I ask him to fill it up, caulk it?

[image: Picture of crack]

Comment: Has your contractor "completed" the job in his opinion, or is he still on site? To me that entire area screams "incomplete" to me.

Comment: What's below the crack? If it's just to the ground outside the foundation it's not likely an issue, assuming a good caulk seal further in.

Comment: I think it's still outside the foundation, but I'm not sure how sealed it is inside.

Comment: No comment, I just gotta laugh at your username.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what your contract with the contractor states. If it wasn't mentioned, you should have it fixed either by him or someone else. If it was mentioned, have him fix it. I would be looking to chip any loose mortar out of there and spreading new mortar in that whole area. As it is now, water will most certainly get under there and could leak into the house under the floor.

Comment: Vinyl patch would be better than mortar.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of the leaking issue.

Comment: What kind of vinyl patch would this be @isherwood? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=vinyl+concrete+patch

Comment: Note that some window installations want the bottom left open enough that any water which gets in can drain out...